# Change orientation - something instead of sleep

Tags: java, android, integration-testing, sleep

I'm trying make a test, which check behavior of my app after a lot of changed orientation.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            mActivityTestRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            mActivityTestRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
```

without `sleep` is too fast - my UI will not able to loaded everything before next change orientation.
But ? Thread.sleep don't look good

How to code this better? What I should do instead of tread sleep ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to check that the UI is fully loaded, you can use busy wait:

```
busyWaitFor(() -> isUILoaded(), 10000, 200);
```

with `busyWaitFor` implemented as follows:

```
private static boolean busyWaitFor(BooleanSupplier condition, int timeoutMilSec, int checkIntervalMilSec) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    boolean interrupted;
    do {
        if (condition.getAsBoolean()) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean timeoutReached = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= (long)timeoutMilSec;
        if (timeoutReached) {
            return false;
        }

        interrupted = sleep(checkIntervalMilSec);
    } while(!interrupted);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to check when UI is loaded